# How to install Sketchup 2016 64 bit on 16.04?

Tags: wine

When I try to run Wine on the exe it says that the program requires Windows 7 or later even though it is set to Win7 compatibility in winecfg. I am using Wine 1.8.

I have both the 32 and 64 bit versions downloaded. When I try getting all the libraries listed in a post on Wine's appDB I still get the same error.

Has anyone else been successful in installing Sketchup 2016 with Wine 1.8?

I have now updated to 1.9.20 and it still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

found this nice tutorial
[SketchUp running on Ubuntu 16.04 - Tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/sketchup-ubuntu-xerus.html)
which was pretty helpful
hope it helps